# Java - regular expression - match string begin with asterisk or semi-colon & asterisk

Tags: java, regex

Need to match two scenarios as following.

- 1. every line star with asterisk or before asterisk there is nothing.
- 2. if the line did not started with asterisk, match everything after ";*"

E.g.

```
*
* this is a comment
*
  * this is a comment too
A = B*C;*comment starts from here, but not before C.
```

(line 1-4, and line 5 after C should be caught)

Updated my solution: (^ **.*|(?<=;)\s+*.*|(?<=;)+*.*|(?<=:)\s+*.*|(?<=:)+*.*)

Tested with regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

just wondering if there is better solution.

Thanks for any help to make this moving.
Regards.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting us know. What have you tried so far? What specific problem have you encountered? What is your question? You can't just post requirements and make a broad request for help.

Comment: try using something like this first http://regexr.com/

Comment: So far, I have combined "\\*[^\\n\\r]*+"  and "\\![^\\n\\r]*+" and tested with http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html.

Comment: Just wondering is there is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will do what you're asking for and capture the text for you in a match:

```
(^ *\*.*|;\*.*)
```

We're using a group construct to capture everything, then using an OR (|) to pass in two regular expressions.

To break that down, let's start with the first part between the '(' and the '|':

```
^  = start at the beginning of a line
 * = followed by zero or more spaces (note there's a [space] hiding in there)
\* = followed by an '*'
.* = followed by zero or more of any character (all the way to end of line)
```

For the second part of the expression between the '|' and the ')':

```
;\* = look for ';*'
.*  = followed by zero or more of any character (all the way to end of line)
```

One thing I noticed is that you weren't accounting for possible spaces between the ';' and '*'. If you need that, then we just need to add the 'zero or more spaces' piece to the second part of the expression:

```
(^ *\*.*|; *\*.*) // note [space] characters hiding in there.
```

Here is the 'test file' used to test this:

```
*
* this is a comment
*
  * this is a comment too
A = B*C;*comment starts from here, but not before C.
A = B*C; *comment starts from here, with a space for readability.
```

You can test this out at https://www.regex101.com (or others to your preference).

There are other optimizations you might want like substituting the hard-coded [space] character for the `\s` meta sequence, but I tried to do exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically like so:

```
String line; // Assuming the string you're going through is in this line.
String comment;

if (line.trim().startsWith("* ")){ // Deals with cases where it is just the comment
    comment = line;
} else if (line.contains(";*") { // Deals with cases where the comment is in the line
    comment = line.substring(line.indexOf(";*"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot but I still prefer regular expression.